# Finding the index of a UTF-8 character in a Python string

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to find the index (or indices) of a certain character in a `UTF-8` encoded string in a foreign language (for example the character: `ش`).

I have tried `unicode.find('ش')`, `word.find(u'ش')`, `word.find(u'\\uش')` and also regular expressions: `re.compile(u'\\uش)` to no avail. The funny thing is that in Visual Studio (my IDE using IronPython) in debug mode, `word.find(u'\\uش')` returns the correct index in the variable watch window but it doesn't in the actual code (returns `index=-1`).

I'm reading the strings from a file using the following command:

```
file= codecs.open(file,'r','utf-8')
```

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: How about searching for `u'\u1588'`?  It could be an encoding problem in your source code.

Comment: Using `x.find("ش")` (where `x` is a unicode object) works for me.  If you're typing the character into your interpreter (or into a script), it could be that the console/file encoding is not set right, so the bytes you get when you paste "ش" in aren't the bytes for that character.  You could try searching for the character by codepoint number or fiddling with the file encoding.

Comment: How do I check the script encoding and change it to be UTF-8?

Comment: I tried u'\u1588' and in debug mode it finds it correctly and outputs the index, but when i just run it whether from Visual Studio or on the terminal I get the index as -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you use `codecs` to read the file, it's no longer UTF-8, it's an internal Unicode string representation. This should be completely compatible with Unicode literals in your program.

```
>>> line=u'abcش'
>>> line.find(u'ش')
3
```

**Edit:** My previous test may have been misleading because both strings were entered through the IDE. Here's a better example:

```
>>> f = codecs.open(r'c:\temp\temp.txt', 'r', 'utf-8-sig')
>>> line = f.readline()
>>> print line
This is a test.ش

>>> line.find(u'\u0634')
15
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's still not working for me. I'm working under windows so could it be an encoding inconsistency? I tried running the same program on Red Hat but I still don

Comment: @poeticcrayons, there definitely might be an encoding inconsistency which is why my second example uses `u'\u0634'` - it's not subject to encoding problems. I see in the comments to the question that you were trying `u'\u1588'` which is the wrong character.